# Only One File Created why?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader

Here I read data from database, loop over results, and pass a column value containing an HTML string row to a function. This function extracts `<body>` tag and contents from HTML input.

When a breakpoint is added to debug and I step through code, everything works properly. When breakpoint is removed, only one file is created but no exceptions are thrown. Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            getBody(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MailText"].ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Response.Write(exp.ToString());
        }
    }


public void getBody(string html)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlDocument();
        HD.LoadHtml(html);
        string output = HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body") == null ? HD.DocumentNode.InnerHtml : HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerHtml;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("OnlyBody/") + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".txt"))
        {
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Write(output);
            if (sw != null)
            {
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw exp;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

At first I thought the problem was with file stream, but even after disposing `StreamWriter` the error persists.

Answer (score 3):

When you debug *with breakpoints*, this block of code will return different results:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss")
```

Without breakpoints, the seconds (`ss`) don't increment because the code is executing too quickly.